How to write SOQL on custom address field?
I have created one custom object in that I have one custom address datatype field. Field name is Location__c, I'm able to build dynamic SOQL using this custom field the code is as follows:
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<WrapperClass> searchLocations( String searchString){
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Language__c, Doctor_Specialty__c, Transportation_offering__c, Availability__c, Location__c, Location__City__s, Location__CountryCode__s,Location__PostalCode__s,Location__StateCode__s,Location__Street__s, PCO_GT_Phone__c FROM Practitioner__c';

        if(searchString != null && searchString != ''){
            String searchTerm = '%'+searchString+'%';
            query += ' WHERE ((Location__PostalCode__s LIKE :searchTerm) OR (Location__City__s LIKE :searchTerm) OR (Location__StateCode__s LIKE :searchTerm))';
        }

        

        System.debug('q -->'+query);
        Set<Id> practitionerIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        
        
        
        for(Practitioner__c objPractitioner: Database.query(query)){
            practitionerIdSet.add(objPractitioner.Id);
            
        }
}

I know Location__c field will be compound address field and I want to get records using State names instead of state code but we don't have specific field to get the records using state names. How can we achieve this?

Below approach can be used :

Maintain state code to state mapping in Custom Metadata. Populate the Custom Metadata with the possible pairs of state & state code.

Create a custom field in object and populate the state name based on
state code on insert/update of records.(using Trigger/Flow)

Populate state names once for the already existing data using Apex code.

With the new custom field , you can easily search it using SOQL.
I don't think/know there is OOTB way of achieving this.


Alternate approach :
Instead of using Custom Metadata , try to access the global country-state picklist as stated in this article.
IMO using state code is the correct way of searching since state names can be misspelled.
If you still insist on using state name , you need to be extra careful w.r.t. the data quality.
